# QList and delete

Tags: qt, memory-management, qlist

I have a `QList` with pointers to objects with class type `Model`. I would like to delete appropriately this `QList` after it has being used. I know Qt philosophy is to avoid C-style memory management. How do I `delete` this `QList`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could use [qDeleteAll](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtalgorithms.html#qDeleteAll-2):

```
qDeleteAll(lstMdls);

lstMdls.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

As seen from [an earlier revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11555630/revisions), this was OP's approach:

```
QList<Model*>lstMdls;

get Data(lstMdls);
 /*
  * Do other things
  */
for(int i=0;i<lstMlds.size();i++)
{
    delete lstMdls.first();
}
```