# Cannot prevent of memory leak when remove QList items with qDeleteAll()

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, qlist

I defined a `QList <QPushButton*>` and I want to assign this list to a `QTableWidget` later. But the main problem is just here that when I want to remove all the `QList` items, it give me memory leak event when use of `qDeleteAll()` :

```
// Add QPushButton* pointers to the QList
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
{
    btnList.push_back(new QPushButton("delete"));
}
```

BTW, Except the first method to push pointers, Also I tried this :

```
// Add QPushButton* pointers to the QList with second approach
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
{
    QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton("delete");
    btnList.push_back(btn);
}
```

I tried with two approaches to `delete` QList pointers :

1. Use of `takeAt` method to get the pointer and `delete` the pointer :

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
   {
       delete btnList.takeAt(0);
   }
   btnList.clear();
   ```
2. Use of `qDeleteAll` then `clear` method :

   ```
   // Delete all items
   qDeleteAll(btnList);
   btnList.clear();
   ```

But The memory leak still exist. I used of `msvc2015` compiler on *Visual Studio*

[Also about my problem I found this link but it didnt help ed meThis link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555630/qlist-and-delete)

Comment: How did you find out you have a memory leak?

Comment: Also, depending on your case, it might be a good idea to just give a `parent` to your `QPushButton`s

Comment: @MaxLanghof as you see in my code , I pushed about `5000` pointers in the `qlist` and removed them immediately and I repeated it several times then I realize theres memory leak...

Comment: Again: How did you see the memory leak? Did you just see memory usage increasing? Or was there some actual tool that told you there were leaked allocations at program exit?

Comment: @MaxLanghof I checked the memory usage increasing in windows task manager when I clear the list

Comment: if you set the parent like @ThomasKowalski mentioned there will memory will be reclaimed when the parent is freed. That may or may not be what you need depending on your situation. You may want  to store a shared pointer instead.

Comment: Your test for the leak seems to be flawed. Just because the memory usage in the task manager doesn't go down immediately after you clear the list, doesn't mean there is a memory leak.

Comment: Releasing memory to the OS likely will not happen after a small delete. Remember that the OS gives your c++ process memory in pages (several KB) at a time not a few bytes at a time. This may help a little: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tims/2010/10/28/pdc10-mysteries-of-windows-memory-management-revealed-part-one/

Comment: As QPushButton is a QObject derived, you should delete it with QObject::deleteLater() method. In your case, I will prefer QSharedPointer to store the QPushButton pointer.